# understanding this mergesort algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, mergesort, divide-and-conquer

I have the following code

```
void mergesort(int size, int ar[], int temp[])
{
    if(size <=1)
    {
        return;}
    else
    {
        int i = 0;
        int mid = size/2;

        int *left = &ar[0];
        int *right = &ar[mid];
        int *rend = &ar[size];
        int *lend = right;

        mergesort(mid,left,temp);
        mergesort(size-mid,right,temp);

        for(i=0; i<size;i++)
        {
            if(left < lend && (*left < *right || right >= rend))
            {
                temp[i] = *left++;
            }
            else
            {
                temp[i] = *right++;
            }
        }
        for(i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            ar[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

I couldn't understand how this if statement works:

```
if(left < lend && (*left < *right || right >= rend))
{
   temp[i] = *left++;
}
else
{
   temp[i] = *right++;
}
```

Can you tell me what's going on in there? Why do we have to compare addresses? (left < lend and right >= rend)

Here's how the mergesort function is called from main

```
const int SIZE = 8;
int array[SIZE] = {3,6,1,-9,0,2,4,5};
int temp[SIZE];

mergesort(SIZE, array,temp);
```

Comment: Because arrays stored as sequential memory addresses?

Comment: Consider what would happen if you didn't.  What would prevent reading off the ends of the (sub-)arrays?

Comment: That said, this code looks broken to me.  If `right` reaches the end of the array, then it still gets dereferenced in `*left < *right`, which invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, should be (right >= rend || *left < *right).

Comment: @AbhishekBansal: It's only **not** checked if `left == lend` ;)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth AAh yes! sorry.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You're right about what happens when `right` gets dereferenced. ...Is there anyway I could make it better...and also understand it because I'm totally lost here and I don't really understand what's going on in the if statement. (I'm a beginner).

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth: "It's only not checked if `left == lend`" - You don't need to check it then (and thus shouldn't if you want faster sorting). Since loop iterates through `size` elements only - if there are no elements in `left` array they can only be in `right`. `assert` would be nice though.

Comment: @SergeDundich: Indeed.  The problem I'm talking about occurs when `left < lend` **and** `right == rend`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to choose the input between the left or right sequences, you need to know if the sequence is exhausted. You check this by testing the pointer to see if it's beyond the valid range. `left < lend` returns `true` if the left sequence is *not* exhausted, and `right >= rend` returns `true` if the right sequence *is* exhausted. Thus the `if` will be taken when the left sequence isn't exhausted, and either the left item is less than the right item or the right sequence is exhausted.

If you were following the standard library iterator conventions, you would never check for `<` or `>` in a comparison. `left != lend` and `right == rend` would work just as well in the code you posted.

P.S. two thoughts that aren't part of your question:

1. As noted in the comments, there's undefined behavior lurking in the comparison. You need to test if the right side is exhausted *before* checking the value at the right side pointer.
2. Merge sort is naturally stable if you use the correct comparison. You want any ties to take from the left sequence. In your case of sorting `int`s it doesn't matter since you can't tell one identical `int` from another, but if this was just a key in part of a larger structure it could matter greatly. It's just a matter of replacing `<` with `<=`.

Taking all the above suggestions together you end up with:

```
if (left != lend && (right == rend || *left <= *right))
```

Comment: Thanks you! But I went ahead with your suggestion and changed the `if` test condition. It works fine but I just wanted to know what's going on in there so I just put `std::cout << *right` in the first for-loop, above the `if` statement. At some point `*right` will have a value of (-858993460). I've had the same problem with the `if` test condition i posted. This happens a lot when the array that is passed is in descending order. Does it mean I have to re-write the whole code? But it sorts numbers without problems.

Comment: @DJK, you're running into *undefined behavior* when `*right` is past the end of the array. Anything could happen; you could get a nonsense number, your program could crash, or [demons could fly out of your nose](http://www.infoplease.com/computers/jargon/N/nasal-demons.html). That's why I suggested rearranging the `if` condition so that the test for out-of-bounds would come first. That's OK because `||` is short circuiting, meaning it will skip the second half of the condition if the first half is true.

Answer (score 0):

[Hariprasad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1605999/hariprasad) is right. Then you make a comparison `left < lend`, you compare the addresses of some elements. Because array is a concequtive set of addresses, the pointers can be used like the indexes and iterators. And then you make the comparison `*left < *right`, for example, you compare the values, of course, and determine the less of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems with this code:

1. `int *rend = &ar[size];` -- Reads beyond the end of the array ar
2. `(*left < *right || right >= rend)` -- I believe this should be `(right > (rend - 1) || (*left > *right))` in order to avoid reading beyond the end of ar.

You can work it out for yourself by stepping through the code with an initial array size of 2 or 3.  Either exposes the problems quickly.  I did this quickly in my head but did not test with a debugger.  Caveat Emptor.